# Display text and button in a <td>

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position

I want to display some text and a button in a `<td>` element. Text should be left aligned and button should be on the right of the `<td>`. Both elements should be displayed inline but that is not happening with my code:

```
<td>Name<br>XYZ<a href=""><button style="float: right">Update</button></a></td>
```

I tried making `display: inline` of both text and button but that is not working as well. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working but **td** width is low that's why you cant see it.
give some width to see the effect

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <td width="200px">Name<br>XYZ<a href=""><button style="float: right">Update</button></a></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is rendered the way you want. Try the following fiddle to see the result: 
https://jsfiddle.net/chaith/7r8kbs4b/

```css
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
          Name<br>XYZ<a href=""><button style="float: right">Update</button></a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```